# How to pack a jar without dependency classes in gradle similar to maven

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies, package

How to write a gradle script so that the application jar should be packed without dependency classes similar to maven jar package

Answer (score 4):

The application JAR is always without dependencies, except you use special plugins to create a "fat" JAR where the dependencies are included. If you ask how to set up a Gradle build at all, you should start reading the [Users Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to package a jar from your Android app or library:
I ran into this question because gradle would include 3rd party libraries into my jar when running `gradle assembleRelease`.

The contents of the jar then looked like this:

```
com/android/...
   /myCompany/...
```

For some reason this did not happen when building for debug. Finally I found that changing:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
```

to

```
provided 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
```

would not include the 3rd party libs ...